# Nopcommerce 2.65 image topic path not relative

Tags: image, relative-path, nopcommerce

The images added through editor in nopcommerce 2.6 topic page shows absolute path of localhost server. But when made online, the image path doesn't change to the website name as it should in relative paths. Also I have tried other methods like using ~ . It works offline but not online.

```
<img width="24" height="26" alt="address icon" src="~/../Content/Images/uploaded/add_icon.gif" />
```

The image path is given above. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Use @Url.Content("Image Path")

<img width="24" height="26" alt="address icon" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/uploaded/add_icon.gif") />
```

NOTE: give relative path in that and upload your image in proper folder on server